# Cannot find resource key for StringValidator.maximumLength(int length)

Tags: wicket

I am migrating my Wicket web application from 1.5.8 to 6.1.1. As part of this process, I am updating validators for my text fields. The resource key for my `TextArea` validator is no longer recognised, and I get a standard

```
'sComments' is longer than the maximum of 250 characters.
```

flash message instead of what I was expecting using what I thought was its resource key:

```
Your comments have a length of 255, which is longer than the maximum of
250 characters that we allow. Please would you amend your comments and try again.
```

Has anyone else come across this problem or can help me name my resource key to get this to work in Wicket 6.1.1?

My old 1.5.8 resource key

```
sComments.StringValidator.maximum
```

works in Wicket 6.1.1 (the documentation states that for backwards compatibility reasons resource keys of form StringValidator.* are still checked), but I want to move to the "modern" way of doing things before it fails with a future version of Wicket.

HTML CODE

```
<textarea wicket:id="sComments" cols="50" rows="5"
 tabindex="5"
></textarea>
```

JAVA CODE

```
private static final int M_N_MAX_LEN_MESSAGE = 250;

// The matching HTML "textarea" component has no maximum length attribute
TextArea<String> taComments = new TextArea<String>("sComments");
// taComments.add(new MaximumLengthValidator(M_N_MAX_LEN_MESSAGE));    1.5.8 code
taComments.add(StringValidator.maximumLength(M_N_MAX_LEN_MESSAGE));
frmForm.add(taComments);
```

PROPERTIES FILE EXTRACT

```
# The resource key that worked in Wicket 1.5.8
# sComments.StringValidator.maximum = Your comments have a length of \
# ${length}, which is longer than the maximum of ${maximum} characters \
# that we allow. Please would you amend your comments and try again.

# Wicket 6.1.1 resource key that does not work
sComments.RangeValidator.maximum = Your comments have a length of \
${length}, which is longer than the maximum of ${maximum} characters \
that we allow. Please would you amend your comments and try again.
```

(I have also tried:

```
sComments.RangeValidator.Maximum
sComments.RangeValidator.MaximumValidator
sComments.MaximumValidator
sComments.RangeValidator.minimum
sComments.RangeValidator.range
sComments.RangeValidator.exact
```

without success.)

Comment: Works fine here, in which properties file did you declare the key?

Comment: @svenmeier The HTML, Java and properties files are all in the same folder with names "PageFeedback.html", "PageFeedback.java" and "PageFeedback.properties" respectively. Is this now an incorrect naming scheme for Wicket 6?

Comment: That looks fine, check the resource keys by enabling logging of resource keys. For log4j: log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket.util.resource=DEBUG

Comment: @svenmeier Thanks. I made logging more sensitive for "org.apache.wicket.core.util.resource". It seems to me that the correct resource key is of the form "sComments.StringValidator.maximum", despite what the javadoc for StringValidator recommends ("sComments.RangeValidator.maximum").

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the correct resource key for Wicket 6.1.1 for this validator is of the form `sComments.StringValidator.maximum`, despite that the javadoc for StringValidator recommends resource keys of the form `sComments.RangeValidator.maximum`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't like the idea of changing the javadoc myself. I am not a Wicket developer (I just use Wicket) and so I am likely to have missed something.